# What does this specific notation mean?

Tags: notation, orthogonal-polynomials, pochhammer-symbol

In *[Bilinear generating functions for orthogonal polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9704016v1)* ([PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9704016.pdf)) the following equation appears under Theorem 2.3.:

[image]

How should I interpret the $j$-indexed denominator? I am familiar with the pochhammer symbol notation, however these typically only have one parameter (on top of the integer index).

Thanks.